# Emacs regex replace while re-using part of the expression in the replacement

Tags: regular-expressions

I sometimes need to do replacements which would involve using matched parts for the output.

For example, I would like to replace

```
varName->doWork()
```

with

```
::doWork(varName, 42)
```

whatever varName actually is.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's doable. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `query-replace-regexp`:

- from: `^\(\w+\)->\([^(]+\)()`
- to: `::\2(\1, 42)`

But if it's a recurring pattern, it's best to solidify it in a
function, instead of entering the regex each time.

Comment: Hmmm, isn't it `::\2(\1, 42)`?

Comment: Oops, you're right.